# 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Material Output" not found' Blender Export for .I3d

Tags: export

[image: Failed when trying to export a mod with texture to .i3d (standard format for 3d objects for the Giant Editor[ Mod Engine for Farming Simmulator]), but with texture there is no problem, but I want to send it with texture, Material Output is present in all textures so I don't think this is a problem, I'm new to blender so if you can let me know about something I did]
Failed when trying to export a mod with texture to .i3d (standard format for 3d objects for the Giant Editor[ Mod Engine for Farming Simmulator]), but with texture there is no problem, but I want to send it with texture, Material Output is present in all textures so I don't think this is a problem, I'm new to blender so if you can let me know about something I did

Comment: The third-party addon (which we can't support here) probably hasn't been updated to work with Blender version 4 because the APIs have changed. You'll need to check with the addon author and see if there's a newer version.

Comment: I suggest setting Blender's language to english in the preferences before you open the model, the node names are automatically translated when you setup the shader tree and the addon seems to refer to the node by names which is case and language sensitive : `Saida de material` should be `Material Output`. You can also rename the node in your interface but you'll have to do it for every material